# nodejs apache htaccess configuration issue

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, ghost-blog

I have a nodejs ghost application running on my shared hosting A2 provider.
The application is a ghost instance listening at port 50754.

Since I have multiple domains, call it a.com & b.com, assuming the ghost instance must respond at b.com, I created an .htaccess file following simple rules expressed by the hoster, to create a configuration to redirect the surf to the correct nodejs running port.

The .htaccess configuration code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?b.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:50754/ [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?b.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:50754/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

The strange thing is, if I surf to b.com or www.b.com, the returning address will be http://www.b.com/index.html.var/, that address not recognized as a valid one will generate an error in the ghost application.

The other strange thing is if I surf to other URIs, for instance, b.com/tags, everything works, but if I try to reach the root I got the strange path and thing will not work as expected.

The latest strange thing is, on the first time both `b.com` & `www.b.com` had worked fine, after (some?) first time the strange path appeared and now any URI address I configure always receives an error surfing to `...root/index.html.var/`

I tried many solutions but nothing seems to work to restore the correct handling of the ghost home page.

Answer (score 1):

If you can post here the site config of the apache server it will be great.
It seems the problem is not in your .htaccess but in your /etc/apache2/sites-available/.conf

Try to post them here and maybe I could be more useful :)